# CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/plotly/win-64/current_repodata.json>

Tags: python, anaconda, plotly

Good day all,
I tried to install the plotly package on my new work laptop (Windows 10) with the following code:

```
conda install -c plotly plotly
```

and I encountered the following error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/plotly/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
'https://conda.anaconda.org/plotly/win-64'
```

I have tried the following:

1. Installing the package using my home wifi instead of the company's
2. Executing `conda config --set ssl_verify no`
3. Executing `conda config --set ssl_verify false`
4. Copying the 2 files (libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll, libssl-1_1-x64.dll) from Anaconda3\Library\bin to Anaconda3\DLLs.

Interestingly, I was unable to find **current_repodata.json** file in https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/.

Does anyone know how do I create this **current_repodata.json** file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problems and tried the above options to my dismay.
But somewhere on the internet I had read an answer about using VPN and try different servers and then install using conda.
This seems to work for me now.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you in a corporate network behind a proxy?
This issue looks to me like you don't have connection to the internet and your proxy is blocking the connection to https://conda.anaconda.org/plotly/win-64/current_repodata.json

Please try this guide to use conda behind a proxy:
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/proxy/